# How to get 1280x1280 from 3840x2160 output stream without scaling?

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer, nvidia-jetson

My goal is to get 1280x1280 frame from nvarguscamerasrc. The problem is  that `nvarguscamerasrc` scaled the 3840x2160 frame to 1280x720. The consequence is that the bottom of the frame is always black.

JetsonCamera.py

```
def gstreamer_pipeline(
    # Issue: the sensor format used by Raspberry Pi 4B and NVIDIA Jetson Nano B01 are different
    # in Raspberry Pi 4B, this command
    # $ libcamera-still --width 1280 --height 1280 --mode 1280:1280
    # uses sensor format 2328x1748.
    # However, v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext do not have such format.
    capture_width=1920,
    capture_height=1080,
    display_width=640,
    display_height=360,
    framerate=21,
    flip_method=0,
):
    return (
        "nvarguscamerasrc ! "
        "video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), "
        "width=(int)%d, height=(int)%d, "
        "format=(string)NV12, framerate=(fraction)%d/1 ! "
        "nvvidconv flip-method=%d ! "
        "video/x-raw, width=(int)%d, height=(int)%d, format=(string)BGRx ! "
        "videoconvert ! "
        "video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR ! appsink"
        % (
            capture_width,
            capture_height,
            framerate,
            flip_method,
            display_width,
            display_height,
        )
    )

class Camera(object):
    frame_reader = None
    cap = None
    previewer = None

    def __init__(self, width=640, height=360):
        self.open_camera(width, height)

    def open_camera(self, width=640, height=360):
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(gstreamer_pipeline(flip_method=0, display_width=width, display_height=height), cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
        if not self.cap.isOpened():
            raise RuntimeError("Failed to open camera!")
        if self.frame_reader == None:
            self.frame_reader = FrameReader(self.cap, "")
            self.frame_reader.daemon = True
            self.frame_reader.start()

    def getFrame(self, timeout = None):
        return self.frame_reader.getFrame(timeout)

class FrameReader(threading.Thread):
    queues = []
    _running = True
    camera = None
    def __init__(self, camera, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.camera = camera
 
    def run(self):
        while self._running:
            _, frame = self.camera.read()
            while self.queues:
                queue = self.queues.pop()
                queue.put(frame)
    
    def addQueue(self, queue):
        self.queues.append(queue)

    def getFrame(self, timeout = None):
        queue = Queue(1)
        self.addQueue(queue)
        return queue.get(timeout = timeout)

    def stop(self):
        self._running = False
```

main.py

```
exit_ = False

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    camera = Camera(width=1280, height=1280)

    while not exit_:
        global frame
        frame = camera.getFrame(2000)
        cv2.imshow("Test", frame)

        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('q'):
            exit_ = True
```

[image: frame's bottom is black]

Comment: what you're taking issue with is the "letterboxing". do you want to _stretch_ the frame, i.e. _not_ maintain its sample aspect ratio, i.e. make rectangular pixels? I'm sure gstreamer can give you a result that doesn't apply letterboxing but simply does the rescale, stretching the data to fit.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I want to mimic `libcamera-still -t 5000 --width 1280 --height 1280 --mode 1280:1280` which uses `2328x1748` sensor format. So the frame generated by `Raspberry Pi 4B with ArduCAM IMX519` and `NVIDIA Jetson Nano B01 with ArduCAM IMX519` stays the same.